# Can't access indexed tuple

Tags: python, tuples, key, tf-idf

I'm trying to traverse through a dictionary that essentially contains tuples and keys for tuples like this:

```
(101940039, 'yoel'): 0.0016034940264139383, 
(101940039, 'yossi'): 0.004810482079241815, 
(101940039, 'youngmen'): 0.0016034940264139383}
```

I need to access the value of the key, i.e., the string of the tuple. I tried many things, like converting to the dictionary, using key[0] just gives me "'int' object is not subscribable"..

```
    def matching_score(k, tokens, tf_idf_score):
    print("Matching Score")
    query_weights = {}
    for word in tokens:
        for key, value in tf_idf_score.items():
            **if key in word**:
                try:
                    query_weights[key[0]] += tf_idf_score[key]
                except:
                    query_weights[key[0]] = tf_idf_score[key]
        
        query_weights = sorted(query_weights.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    print("")
    
    l = []
    
    for i in query_weights[:10]:
        l.append(i[0])
    
    print(l)
```

Comment: What does `**if key in word**` mean? Would you mind sharing a part of tuples with us?

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani 
101940036 (101940036, 'abil') (101940036, 'ad') (101940036, 'addit')

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani ```**if key in word**``` I just highlighted that part.  Essentially, I'm trying to use a value in the tuple's key to see if that's the same in the token dict

Comment: Thank you for the information, Gelmis. But the thing is, the mentioned dictionary can not be fully understandable! In a dictionary, there should be some keys that refer to some values. In your case, I do not see where `101940036` refers to.

Comment: I've edited the snippet. The part on the left are the parts that I'm trying to access, well, only the string part.

Comment: Thanks for the update! You have used `items` function on your dictionary. What would be wrong with calling the `key` and trying to access the second index on the key(`key[1]`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is a recreation of your data as a dictionary:

```
d1 = {(101940039, 'yoel'): 0.0016034940264139383, 
      (101940039, 'yossi'): 0.004810482079241815, 
      (101940039, 'youngmen'): 0.0016034940264139383}
```

With `keys()` it is possible to access the keys. At the same time, we want to convert them into a list.

```
list(d1.keys())
```

The result is a list of tuples.

`[(101940039, 'yoel'), (101940039, 'yossi'), (101940039, 'youngmen')]`

To access individual items in this nested list: first, use the index of the list to select the desired list, and second, use the index of the tuple to select the desired item within.

```
list(d1.keys())[0][1]
```

`'yoel'`

To get all the string elements of the key tuples:

```
for i in range(len(d1)):
    print(list(d1.keys())[i][1])
```

`yoel`

`yossi`

`youngmen`

Comment: Good god.. Thank you.. This one really stressed me out